# Get data from SQL Server table and update into XML file content

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I would like to get data from sql server table and update into xml file content (xml tag). This means that when a user update the database, it will automatically update the data for xml file too. The question is, is that impossible to be done? I have search in google the solution but there are none. Can anyone help me?

This is the sample of xml file content:

```
<CITE>
<CITE_ONE>ABC_2015_255</CITE_ONE>
<CITE_TWO>DEF_2015_255</CITE_TWO>
<CITE_THREE>GHI_2015_255</CITE_THREE>
</CITE>
```

So the sql server table will consists of CITE_ONE, CITE_TWO & CITE_THREE.

The content in xml file content must be same in sql server table.

This is my code section for the controller:

```
// GET: Tests/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            Test tests = db.Tests.Find(id);

            return View(cases);
        }

        // POST: Tests/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Tests tests)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tests).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                Success(string.Format("Successfully edited!"), true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            Danger("Please try again.");
            return View(cases);
        }
```

As you guys can see, Here I pass id as parameter for edit. it can be successfully edited. What I want next is, how can I update my existing xml file according to the one in sql server table?

Comment: Is there other data in the file or is it just what is in the data returned from the table? Also is it a single value from a single row or the result of a query from the table? Please provide example and details.

Comment: Step 1) read data from database, Step 2), Update xml. Yes it is possible, but you should start with step 1 first. then try step 2, and when you have a problem, then come and see us

Comment: you can create a little background task with C# that checks the database, for example, every 1 minute and if there was any difference between XML and table, then update XML.

Comment: There is another data in the file, it's just that I want to update certain info only @EdneyHolder but it must be same as the sql server table db

Comment: You haven't included, the format of the xml file, the data you are trying to read, or any information that can help us help you. You also havent shown where you are in this problem, what you do know or dont know, what errors you are getting, ect..

Comment: @TheGeneral How can I update the xml file?

Comment: Does that mean the app will always check the condition if there are differences? like real time? @MeysamFaghfouri

Comment: Yes. but it works well with small to medium tables (in terms of data size) but when your data is big I'm not sure that this approach will work appropriately or not.
with big data, you can use a trigger to pass new items to a web service and inside that web service, update the XML file @lara

Answer (score 1):

First create a trigger for update on the table and or fiels(s) you are concerned with.

Next select the data to xml format

```
DECLARE @xmlResults varchar(max);

SET @xmlResults  = SELECT <Fields to include in reulsts>
FROM <Your Table>
WHERE <Your Where Clause>
FOR XML RAW;
);
```

Now Output to file

```
declare @fn varchar(200) = '<Your file name including pat>';

declare @cmd varchar(8000) = concat('echo ', @xmlResults, ' > "', @fn, '"');

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output
```

Comment: Does this mean it will output a xml file? what about it updates that existing xml file?

Comment: @lara "FOR XML RAW;" returns the data in XML format. "exec xp_cmdshell cmd,  no_output" executes the command built in "declare cmd varchar(8000) = concat('echo ', xmlResults, ' > "', fn, '"');" which says To echo (write) the value of xmkresults (The xml results of the query) to the file fn